# MySQL - cant create/write to file error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import data into a MySQL database using a .sql file and phpmyadmin.

I get the following error in phpmyadmin

```
MySQL said:
#1 - Can't create/write to file '/usr/local/mysql/data/skeleton/actions.MYI' (Errcode: 2)
```

I have created the skeleton database and am trying to import data into the database.

There is no `'/usr/local/mysql/data/skeleton'` folder but the readme instructions did not say I had to create one.

How should I go about debugging / fixing this?

Comment: Use a folder that exists and where the MySQLd has write access.

Comment: Although I don't get why you need to write into a file when you IMPORT data into your database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the permissions on the MySQL data directory don't allow MySQL access. Can you try creating a test database from the command line client?

```
CREATE DATABASE foo;
```

I suspect you'll get the same error, which indicates something is wrong with your installation. What's your operating system and how did you install MySQL?